# Error in function call

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following function:

```
-(void) CalLevels: (NSMutableArray *)rPrices: (NSMutableDictionary *) rLevels: (float) nClose: (float) nHigh: (float) nLow: (float) nOpen {...}
```

I am calling the above function as follows:

```
[self CalLevels:rm.rPrices  rLevels:rm.rLevels nClose:nCloseD nHigh:nHighD nLow:nLowD nOpen:nOpenD];
```

I get the warning method not found.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: First examples signature does not match the seconds signature. Look at rPrices and nOpen

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Please forgive me for not knowing.  I am very new to obj-c.  Can you elaborate why the two signatures do not match?  If you will give example for one of those that do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call it like that:

```
[self CalLevels:rm.rPrices  :rm.rLevels :nCloseD :nHighD :nLowD :nOpenD];
```

or change the method declaration, since `rLevel` and its friends are the internal method name of the variables, not part of the method name.

The correct way is either the one above, or change the method signature:

```
-(void) CalLevels: (NSMutableArray *)rPrices  rLevels: (NSMutableDictionary *) rLevels nClose: (float) nClose nHigh: (float) nHigh nLow: (float) nLow nOpen : (float) nOpen {...}
```

Comment: My intention is to pass nCloseD, nHighD, etc to modify the objects rPrices and rLevels inside the method.  CalLevels id the method and everything else is parameters (rLevels and rPrices get modified inside the method)  What is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Your method declaration is busted. You write:

```
-(void) CalLevels: (NSMutableArray *)rPrices: (NSMutableDictionary *) rLevels: (float) nClose: (float) nHigh: (float) nLow: (float) nOpen
```

This declares a method named `CalLevels::::::`. The `rLevels`, `nClose` and all that are parsed as the parameters' names. You probably meant to declare one named `alLevels:rPrices:rLevels:nClose:nHigh:nLow:nOpen:`. That would look more like this:

```
- (void)CalLevels:(NSMutableArray *)levels rPrices:(NSMutableDictionary *)rPrices rLevels:(float)rLevels nClose:(float)nClose nHigh:(float)nHigh nLow:(float)nLow nOpen:(float)nOpen
```

(I'm guessing that `nOpen` is meant to be a float.)

Comment: I have it like:- (void)CalLevels:(NSMutableArray *)levels rPrices:(NSMutableArray *)rPrices rLevels:(NSMutableDictionary *) rLevels nClose:(float)nClose nHigh:(float)nHigh nLow:(float)nLow nOpen:(float)nOpen { ...}  and I call it by: [self CalLevels:rm.rPrices  :rm.rLevels :nCloseD :nHighD :nLowD :nOpenD];  still I get method -CalLevels:::::::: not found.

Comment: @saman01 do you really need to a "levels" array and a "levels" dictionary? From the comment above your first parameter is a "levels" array and your third parameter is a "levels" dictionary. Also, you would need to call the method like this: `[self CalLevels:aLevelsArray rPrices:rm.rPrices rLevels:aLevelsDictionary nClose:nCloseD nHigh:nHighD nLow:nLowD nOpen:nOpenD];`

Comment: @saman01: You would call it like you wrote in your question. The problem was that your declaration was was for a method called `CalLevels::::::` (because it interpreted `rPrices` etc. as the name of an argument with no accompanying text in the method name), whereas you wanted a method called `CalLevels:rPrices:rLevels:nClose:nHigh:nLow:nOpen:`. So use the declaration you have now and call it like you were doing originally.

Answer (score 1):

What @MByD wrote will work but if you want to adhere to the [Naming Conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) you need to rename your method. Right now your method is named `CalLevels::::::` and `rLevels`, `nClose`, etc. are the parameter names that are not part of the name. If you want to follow the *Naming Conventions*, you need to:

- Start the name with a lowercase letter. `CalLevels...` is wrong, `calLevels...` is right.
- Use keywords before all arguments. `calLevels::::::` is wrong, `calLevels:rPrices:rLevels:nClose:nHigh:nLow:nOpen:` is right.

Resulting in something like this:

```
-(void)calLevels:(NSMutableArray *)rLevels rPrices:(NSMutableDictionary *)rPrices nClose:(float)nClose nHigh:(float)nHigh nLow:(float)nLow nOpen:(float)nOpen;
```